# Scala - extracting first element of inner array of strings from nested arrays of strings

Tags: arrays, string, scala

I am new to Scala and could use some help.  I have an RDD that is Array[Array[String]]. I need to extract the 1st element in each internal array.  Sample records look like:

`res21: Array[Array[String]] = 
Array
(Array(217.150.149.167, -, 4712, [15/Sep/2013:23:56:06, +0100], "GET, /ronin_s4.jpg), 
 Array(104.184.210.93, -, 28402, [15/Sep/2013:23:42:53, +0100], "GET, /titanic_2200.jpg), 
 Array(37.91.137.134, -, 36171, [15/Sep/2013:23:39:33, +0100], "GET, /ronin_novelty_note_3.jpg)
)`

I need the results to be:

```
217.150.149.167
104.184.210.93
37.91.137.134
```

Thanks, Rachel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it okay if your final collection is an `Array`?
You can try:

```
res21.flatMap(_.headOption) // headOption to be safe and flatMap to flatten the collection
```